# Angular 2 Code Snippet extension (from Mads) not working in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, angular, resharper

I should have quite a lot of snippets available to me but when I type in "ng" I am not seeing them. All I get is what is in the below image. Is there a chance Resharper can be overriding it? If so, does anyone know how to resolve it? I have not been able to research a solution so this was my last hope.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default key for using an non resharper snippet when resharper is installed is ctrl k x that should bring up the menu.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to invoke Visual Studio's own code snippets when using ReSharper.

If you want to show VS's own code snippets menu, set your own shortcut for "Edit | Intellisense | Insert Snippet" item (via VS options -> Environment -> Keyboard).

If you want to have VS's code snippets in code completion, you can override code completion to come from Visual Studio instead of ReSharper. Go to ReSharper | Options | Environment | IntelliSense | General, and set code completion type to 'Visual Studio'. But please note that this disables ReSharper's own code completion.

ReSharper will include Angular 2 live templates since 2017.2, created a ticket for that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-464025.